# Trying to use addHandler to a dynamically created component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component that dynamically generates a field using $A.createComponent.  I want to add a change handler to the created  component, and it fires as expected.  However, I get an error saying that the controller action is not found.

Here's my component's controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    // make the field component.
    $A.createComponent(component.get('v.fieldDefinition'), component.get('v.fieldAttributes'),function(cmp,status,error){
        if(component.get('v.fieldDefinition').startsWith('ui:')){
            // need to add a handler for standard ui: components.  
            // custom components register them on their own.
            cmp.addHandler('change',cmp, 'c.handleFieldUpdated');
        }
        component.set('v.cmp',cmp);
    });
},
handleFieldUpdated : function(component,event,helper){
    console.log('field updated');
}
```

The above init block generates a component, such as "ui:inputText".  Then I use "cmp.addHandler" so I can tell it to call my "handleFieldUpdated" controller action when the value changes.

The change event fires, however the error message I receive is "Uncaught Unknown controller action 'handleFieldUpdated'"

I've tried using the following syntax in my addHandler to assign the controller action, and none have worked:

"c.handleFieldUpdated"
 "component.get('c.handleFieldUpdated')"
 "handleFieldUpdated"

All with the same error message.  Is there another way to assign the correct controller action to the generated UI component?

**EDIT::  I tried the following using "addEventHandler" as suggested in the comments.**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    // make the field component.
    $A.createComponent(component.get('v.fieldDefinition'), component.get('v.fieldAttributes'),function(cmp,status,error){
        if(component.get('v.fieldDefinition').startsWith('ui:')){
            // need to add a handler for standard ui: components.  
            // custom components register them on their own.
            cmp.addEventHandler('change', component.getReference("c.handleFieldUpdated"));
        }
        component.set('v.cmp',cmp);
    });
},
handleFieldUpdated : function(component,event,helper){
    console.log('field updated');
}
```

This gives me the following error: "Action failed: c:FieldComponent$controller$doInit [cmp.addEventHandler is not a function]"

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.  The addHandler call needs to reference the parent component, not the child that was generated.  So it needs to change from this:

```
cmp.addHandler('change',cmp, 'c.handleFieldUpdated');
```

to this:

```
cmp.addHandler('change',component, 'c.handleFieldUpdated');
```

Comment: addHandler has been deprecated, and you should instead be using addEventHandler, as outlined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_handler.htm).

Comment: @sfdcfox when I add the new syntax::    cmp.addEventHandler("click", component.getReference("c. handleFieldUpdated"));     I get the following message: "Action failed: c:FieldComponent$controller$doInit [cmp.addEventHandler is not a function]"